# Fastest route to creating MSI with nant

Tags: wix, windows-installer, nant

I have a current build process which does a .NET build using MSBuild and then I end up with all my project DLLs/EXEs and 3rd party DLLs in the same directory with some resources in a sub-directory.

I would like to package this bundle up into an MSI.  I have looked around and found WiX and it has nant tasks available.  However it appears I need to maintain a .wxs file with references to the full list of DLLs.  I would really like to avoid having to manual maintain this file or any other file.

I actually have many projects that use a shared build script so every project builds in a consistent fashion.  I would therefore like the MSI step to be automated as well otherwise every project has to maintain the .wxs file with the current DLL list + any resource files.

Is it possible to use WiX or another any tool where I can just point it at a directory and get it to package every file/sub-directory without needing a config file?

Comment: You need to look into heat and its associated NAnt/MSBuild tasks.  There are many questions here on SO about Wix and Heat.

Comment: Here is a link to the [HeatFile Task](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msbuild_task_reference_heatfile.htm) XML wrapper documenation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to [the documentation for Heat](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm) (part of Wix) and use that in your build process.

As an example, something like this should work:

```
heat.exe dir C:\Build\Release -srd -ag -suid -cg AutoHarvestCG -out c:\Build\Setup\AutoHarvest.wxs
```

Then `AutoHarvest.wxs` will be automatically generated and contain all files from `C:\Source\Release` under a `ComponentGroup` called `AutoHarvestCG` which you can include with a `ComponentGroupRef` element in any Feature element.

You'll still have to maintain a .wxs file with your Product, Package, and Feature information, along with any custom actions you might have.